# Ajax insert data to database

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to insert data using Ajax. When I click the button(accept) value 1 should be inserted and button should  be changed to accepted. I have tried the following code

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#submit').on('click', function() {
            var name = $('#app').val();
            if (name.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'approve.php',
                    method: 'POST'
                    data: { app: name },
                    success: function() {
                        alert("success");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML code

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="app" value="1"/>
  <input id='submit' type='submit' value='Accept'> 
</form>
```

approve.php is

```
$u_id  = $_SESSION['UserID'];
 $appinfo = $_POST['app'];
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_bides SET selected='$appinfo' WHERE bidder_id = '".$u_id."'" or die(mysql_error());
$Result = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

When I run this nothing happens. Please help!!

Comment: this `$('#app').on('#submit',...` doesn't make any sense imO. eighter you set the listener to the form and let it trigger on `'submit'`, or you make a on 'click' listener to the submit-button.

Comment: Try the basics, `$('#app').submit` will call the AJAX

Comment: `submit` event need to be bound to the `form`, your code really doesn't make sense

Comment: This may be a silly comment: But you have included the jQuery library havent you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" id="app">
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="submit">
```

JS

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
var name = $('#app').val();

$.ajax({
    url: 'approve.php',
    data:"app="+ name,
    success:function(){
           alert("success");
    }
  });
});
```

approve.php (using PDO)

```
include('connection.php');


$u_id  = $_SESSION['UserID'];

if(isset($_POST['app'])) {
    $appinfo  = $_POST['app'];

    $queryUpdate = $YourConnectionName->prepare("UPDATE tbl_bides SET selected=:appinfo WHERE bidder_id=:u_id");
    $queryUpdate->execute(array(':u_id' => $u_id, ':appinfo'=> $appinfo));
}
```

connection.php

```
$username = 'YourUsernameOfDatabase';
$password = 'YourPasswordOfDatabase';

try {
    $YourConnectionName = new PDO('mysql:host=Yourhost; dbname=YourDatabaseName', $username, $password);
    $YourConnectionName->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $YourConnectionName->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'You are not connected';
    $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: but still nothing happens. It does not enter to the database

Comment: Edited, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript is wrong. First, you're trying to set a 'submit' event handler on a hidden form field. Only `<form>` fires the `submit` event naturally. Second, you aren't setting the `method` parameter so $.ajax is submitting your data via `GET` which means your PHP code won't see any values.

You are better off setting a click event on the submit button:

```
 <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#submit').on('click', function() {
            var name = $('#app').val();

            if (name.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'approve.php',
                    method: 'POST'
                    data: { app: name },
                    success: function() {
                        alert("success");
                    }
               });
           }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And you approve.php:

```
$u_id  = $_SESSION['UserID'];
$appinfo = $_POST['app'];
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_bides SET selected='$appinfo' WHERE bidder_id = '$u_id'";
$Result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Add One more parameter in ajax for submitting post data 

    $.ajax({
                url: 'approve.php',
                type: 'POST'
                data:"app="+ name,
                success:function(){
                    alert("success");
                }
           }));
```

Comment: Hello change data: { app: name }  to data: { 'app': name } in ajax code

Comment: Hi, I have no idea what is wrong, I tried that as well. Nothing happens

Comment: Just echo $appinfo and $u_id value in approve.php  and change success:function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }  so that it will be clear problem is not from values

Comment: no I dont get it in that page. approve.php doesnt show because ajax code I run in my index page

Comment: Yes.To display that code you have to change success parameter in ajax to success:function(result){ alert(result); }  this will alert the value.

Comment: Does you put session_start(); in connection.php  or approve.php file.bcs if you not geting $u_id means you are not getting current user id.